# Typescript/React: How can a ref be added to a material-ui Box component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, animation, material-ui, gsap

How can a ***ref*** be added to a **[material-ui Box](https://material-ui.com/components/box/)** component in React, using TypeScript? This is important to allow animation libraries like [GreenSock / GSAP](https://greensock.com/gsap/) to animate nodes. Per [material-ui docs](https://material-ui.com/api/root-ref/), using the itemRef will not work because it requires the use of *findDOMNode* which is deprecated in strict mode (prep for concurrent React) and further is likely to break due to virtual DOM rendering.

Comment: Can you provide some coding sample that may emphasize what you are trying to do?

Comment: @MEDZ, thanks for the response. I have found several other posts on the Box ref limitation, posted on each, and provided a summary with a workaround, below.

Comment: Specify setting in title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without the ability to associate a *ref* to **ALL MATERIAL-UI GENERATED NODES**, there is not a reliable way to integrate animation libraries targeting specific nodes.

There are several related issues on the material-ui GitHub project. I posted a workaround on **[Issue #17010](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/17010)** until such time as material-ui includes the ability to add *ref* to all generated nodes.

**Related Issues:**

- How can a ref be added to a Box component? [#19284](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/19284)
- [Box] Allow ref on Box [#19275](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/19275)
- ref missing from Box in TypeScript definition **[#17010](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/17010)**

**Interim Workaround:**

```
// 1. Import style library, either Emotion or Styled-Components
import styled from "@emotion/styled";

// 2. Recreate the Material-UI Box with a styled component
const StyledBox = styled(Box)``;

// 3. Usage in the render
<StyledBox ref={boxRef}>Box Content</StyledBox>
```

**NOTE:** Using @material-ui/core/styles does not work, requiring the use of [emotion](https://emotion.sh/docs/introduction) or [styled-components](https://styled-components.com). *We are forced to use emotion over styled-components due to an animation flicker problem uniquely generated by styled-components.*

Comment: It looks like this is [fixed in material-ui v5](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/17010#issuecomment-724187064), which is in alpha.